# saving arrays into multiple columns instead of appending as one big column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

My program includes a loop process, which generates two arrays `predict_result` and `ground_truth`, at each iteration. Each array is of dimension, e.g., `[100,1]`. I want to save each array into a new column in separate csv files.

This is the main code snippet. However, I found that after executing the program, each array is appended into the original array. In other words, I get two large single-column files, instead of two multi-column files. If I remove the `mode='a'` in the `to_csv` function, the new column will over-write old columns.

```
with open(file_1, 'w+') as predict_csv, open(file_2 , 'w+') as truth_csv:

     for ij in range(0,100):
         #  some other code here
         # predict_result is an array of shape, e.g., [100,1]
        # ground_truth  is also an array of shape, e.g.,[100,1]
         predict_result_pd = pd.DataFrame(predict_result)
         ground_truth_pd = pd.DataFrame(ground_truth)
         predict_result_pd.to_csv(predict_csv,header=False,mode='a')
         ground_truth_pd.to_csv(truth_csv,header=False,mode='a')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think opening in append mode is the right approach to add columns, this works only for adding rows.

But you could this:

```
data = []
for some loop:
   data.append[some_row] # make sure some row has shape (n,), not (n,1)
data = np.array(data).T 
# now your data in arranged in columns
# and you can save it to whatever format you like for example:
np.savetxt("foo.csv", data, delimiter=",")
```